# String to double with 0 tail

Tags: c#

I don't know how to remove the tail of zero on a "double" conversion from a generic currency string in C#.

This is my code

```
double reddito = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("12500,245"), 3);
```

the expected result

```
reddito = 12500.245
```

the real result

```
reddito = 12500.245000000001
```

what is the matter?

Comment: Hmm..i copy your code and got the expected result...

Comment: I got the expected result too.

Comment: but with debug or with Console.writeline? In debug i have this problem

Comment: I have printed using `console.writeline`, no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For currencies it is best to use a decimal type rather than a double. Doubles and floats are essentially approximations of the real number and can quickly get you into trouble with financial calculations. Recommended practice is not to test floats and doubles for equality but allow for a small tolerance around the value for this particular reason.